# Bash shell - How to get return value from "echo >"

Tags: linux, bash, shell

In command line, I use `echo -e "ang?\r\n"> /dev/ttyUSB0` to get data from device and it will return value like this `ang: 30,26,31,28`. Now, I try to do this in a Bash shell and would like to save the return value in a variable but it seems not work for me. My Bash shell

```
#! /bin/ash 
dev_ang=$(echo -e "ang?\r\n"> /dev/ttyUSB0)
echo "Device ang:"
echo $dev_ang | cut -d , -f 3
```

When I run the script, I expect I would get

```
Device ang:
ang: 31
```

but I got

```
ang: 30,26,31,28
Device ang:
```

I think that return value is not saved in `dev_ang`. Is there anything wrong and how do I make the script work correctly?

Comment: But, you have redirected the outpout to the file `/dev/ttyUSB0` so there is no output for $() to capture! If you really want both use the tee command, i.e. `$(echo -e "ang?\r\n"|tee /dev/ttyUSB0)`

Comment: Please note *»return value«* (= exit status) and *»textual output«* are something different. You probably meant the latter.

Comment: @Socowi Oops, I actually I meant the latter, thank you for your remind.

Comment: @GemTaylor I got
`ang: 30,26,31,28`
`Device ang:`
`ang?`

Comment: What exactly is `/dev/ttyUSB0`? It's outputting the `arg: ...` string directly to your terminal, not to the standard output of `echo`.

Comment: `ash` is not `bash`

Comment: @chepner It just is a sensor which can report temperature and surface's angle. The command is a little like at command.